# Rotating linear-elastic sphere

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

If one wants to describe the dynamics of the displacement field of a linear-elastic  and rotating (with constant angular velociy) sphere from a body-fixed co-rotating coordinate system, is it then necessary to include the Coriolis term? I'm very curious about this, because I can't find a book or paper which would clarify this issue.

Comment: What you mean by “linear elastic “ is the sphere surface elastic?

Comment: I mean within linear elasticity theory, that this the displacement field follwing

Comment: ...the equation of motion of linear elasticity theory

Comment: Is the system at steady state?  If so, then there is no Coriolis term.  The sphere is rotating as a deformed rigid body.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you exactly mean with steady state, sorry.  I mean the sphere starts to rotate and then it changes its shape . This shape is then the new equilibrium or steady state.  Is that what you mean with steady state ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Ok, but why is in this case no Coriolis term present? because the displacement field is dynamical and can in general oscillate with a given eigenfrequency around this new equilibrium and therefore it can move relative to the co-rotating frame and hence there should be a Coriolis term

Comment: Why are you assuming that an oscillation must be present.  Isn't the steady state problem a difficult enough analysis to start with?

Comment: Because I'm study phonons of a rotating sphere....